# How to ignore overriding behaviour by puppet agent

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache, theforeman

Let's say i configured the desired state of configuration For ex Minimum = 1.       Incase if my application changes this configuration value to 5,  then puppet overwrites once again to 1.  How this can be avoided?  What i wanted is during installation of my application Minimum value should be set as 1, incase if the application alters it's value, then it should not be overwritten by puppet. how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this happens inside a configuration `file`, you can likely just set its [replace](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-replace) parameter to `false`.